# Button action is not fired for UIButton Inside UIView which is inside UIScrollview in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I want to load set of objects coming from array in vertical scrollview. I have UIScrollview at xib. Programmatically I added photo image, item name, item tags, comment button and likes label to UIView and added UIView to UIScrollview.

I added likes button to UIScrollview but the button action is not firing. Below is my code.
I think some Frames of subviews are over riding that makes button action (likes_ButtonPressed) not fired.

```
-(void)createScrollview
{

    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [scrollview subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) [v removeFromSuperview];

    int x=7;
    int y=0;

    CGRect screenbounds=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

     for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
        {
            ProfileObjCls *profileObjRef = [self.array objectAtIndex:i];

            //NSLog(@"Button Tag is %@",profileObjRef.image_UserLoaded_objInArray);

            UIView *mainView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,310,400)];

            self.photoTagImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y+20,294,320)];
            self.likesLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"BodoniStd-BoldItalic" size:13];
            self.itemNameLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y+340,100,30)];
            commentsButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+155+32, y+340, 40, 40)];
            [commentsButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comment_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            UIButton *photoLikeButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+100, y+340, 40, 40)];
            photoLikeButton.tag=i;
            [photoLikeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like_img_new.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [photoLikeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likes_ButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            self.likesLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+223+32,y+346,310,30)];

            if (profileObjRef.photoLikes==0)
            {
                self.likesLabel.text=@"0 likes";
            }
            else
            {
            self.likesLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ likes",profileObjRef.photoLikes];
            }



            [self.photoTagImgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profileObjRef.image_UserLoaded_objInArray]
                              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"satisfashionplaceholder@568.png"]
                                     completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
             {
                 if (!error && image)
                 {

                 }
             }];

                self.imagetotweet=profileObjRef.image_UserLoaded_objInArray;


                //int y=335;

                //first label - PHOTO NAME
                self.itemNameLbl.text=profileObjRef.photoname;

                self.itemNameLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BodoniStd-Poster" size:14.0];//BodoniStd-Bold
                self.itemNameLbl.textColor  = [UIColor blackColor];

                //second Label - PHOTO DESCRIPTION
                UIFont *cellFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"BodoniStd-BoldItalic" size:13.0];




            [mainView addSubview:commentsButton];
            [mainView addSubview:likesLabel];
            [self.scrollview addSubview:photoLikeButton];
            [self.scrollview bringSubviewToFront:photoLikeButton];
            [mainView addSubview:self.photoTagImgView];
            [mainView addSubview:self.itemNameLbl];

            [mainView addSubview:self.detailsBgImgView];
            [self.scrollview addSubview:likesButton];
            [self.scrollview bringSubviewToFront:likesButton];
            mainView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            self.scrollview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            self.scrollview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            /*
            self.scrollview.exclusiveTouch = YES;
            self.scrollview.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
            self.scrollview.delaysContentTouches = YES;
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;*/
            //self.scrollview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:212.0f/255.0f green:213.0f/255.0f blue:214.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
            [self.scrollview addSubview:mainView];
            [self.view addSubview:self.scrollview];
             y=y+200;
            //x=x+320;
        }
        self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 400*array.count);
        //self.scrollview.contentSize=(CGSizeMake(x, 320));
        self.scrollview.pagingEnabled=YES;
        //[self.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320*tagValue, 0)];
        [self.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 400*tagValue)];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:spinner];

       //[self.scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320*(tagValue-1), 0)];
    }

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return ![view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
}
```

Please suggest any ideas where I went wrong..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: That's hell a lot of code for such problem. Try to analyse the views layout with the Xcode 6 beta if you don't see possibility to do it with the code.

Comment: So you're laying out similar views vertically in a scrollview?  You should be using a table view for this task.  Find a UITableView tutorial and follow it.  It will make your life much easier.